# ios Xcode Debugging - strange bug - Dismissing View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging

I have literally been tearing my hair out for the past couple of days, as I have a bug in my app that seems to strike at random! I thought I would ask on here to see if anyone has had a similar experience.

The app is just crashing when a certain view controller is loaded. But this only seems to happen 1 out of every 25-30 times - so it just seems completely random to me!

The console shows the following error

```
Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller <UINavigationController: 0x1f025c30> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!
```

The app then crashes.

However, there is not actually any code to dismiss this view controller - I use JASidepanels (https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels) however this bug only occurs with one view. So as there is no code to dismiss it, I really am not sure how this is happening. (JASidepanels slides and hides this panel - but this is not called when the view loads)

Below is the symbolicated crash report - I really cannot find much of use in here at all:

```
Incident Identifier: 8E0C4F14-1B7B-4241-A1D3-37AD55F3D432
CrashReporter Key:   fb5a345eac1c4c3ba4fbe6158b1d6af5833f137e
Hardware Model:      iPad2,7
Process:         appName [7665]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/130C6C0F-40E0-4EE7-AD2A-F7CFCFD6C462/appName.app/appName
Identifier:      appName
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-07-02 14:24:24.588 +0100
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.3 (10B329)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  9

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x32f5729e __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3ae1297a objc_exception_throw + 26
2   CoreFoundation                  0x32f56d80 __NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler + 124
3   UIKit                           0x34d6ff92 -[UIView(Hierarchy) subviews] + 326
4   UIKit                           0x34d7b04a -[UIView(Geometry) resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 22
5   UIKit                           0x3519cc28 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _is_layout] + 112
6   UIKit                           0x34d68a8c -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutSubviews] + 68
7   UIKit                           0x34d627fe -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 254
8   QuartzCore                      0x34b0cd86 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 210
9   QuartzCore                      0x34b0c924 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 456
10  QuartzCore                      0x34b0d858 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 12
11  QuartzCore                      0x34b0d23e CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 234
12  QuartzCore                      0x34b0d04c CA::Transaction::commit() + 312
13  QuartzCore                      0x34b0ceac CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned      long, void*) + 56
14  CoreFoundation                  0x32f2c6c8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 16
15  CoreFoundation                  0x32f2a9bc __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 272
16  CoreFoundation                  0x32f2ad12 __CFRunLoopRun + 738
17  CoreFoundation                  0x32e9deb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
18  CoreFoundation                  0x32e9dd44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
19  GraphicsServices                0x36a692e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
20  UIKit                           0x34db32fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
21  appName                         0x0009c1a2 main (main.m:16)
22  libdyld.dylib                   0x3b249b1c start + 0
```

And thread 9 - that crashed:

```
Thread 9 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b310d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b25ecf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b25ea12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b25e8a0 start_wqthread + 4
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> Dismissing a Presented View Controller
>
> When it comes time to dismiss a presented view controller, the
>   preferred approach is to let the presenting view controller dismiss
>   it. In other words, whenever possible, the same view controller that
>   presented the view controller should also take responsibility for
>   dismissing it. Although there are several techniques for notifying the
>   presenting view controller that its presented view controller should
>   be dismissed, **the preferred technique is delegation**. For more
>   information, see “Using Delegation to Communicate with Other
>   Controllers.”

Make sure that you don't dismiss you viewController inside this viewcontroller(according to the documentation). The best way dismiss viewController outside use delegate.
[“Using Delegation to Communicate with Other Controllers.”](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH8-SW9)

Comment: Thanks anton - the only issue is i am not trying to dismiss it! This error is happening right as the view is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
if (![self.presentedViewController isBeingPresented]) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks Omarj - the only issue is i am not trying to dismiss it! This error is happening right as the view is loaded - I dont even have code to dismiss this view controller in the .m file.

Comment: @PaulWalton this Warning appear when you try to present view controller twice.
or your presenting code called twice check that and let me know what u find ?

Comment: @PaulWalton or when you try to present view controller while there is one already presenting.

Comment: I have double checked, and placed an NSLog when it is called - I managed to get it to crash once, and it definitely did not get called twice!

Comment: @larrysanchez u still have issue with that ? plz let us know what happened with u by accept answer or answer the question by your self to let other people know how to solve similar problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is connected with modal/presented view controllers at all.

From the stack trace only one thing is clear - it's a typical exception caused by changing objects in collection while enumerating them in the same time. In this case the collection is probably the of subviews (your main thread is enumerating them).

One of the usual causes is updating the view hierarchy from a secondary thread (not the main thread).

Comment: Thanks Sulthan...i have been thinking the same to be honest - I am just trying to trace what could be accessing that view controller - it is fairly standard - view loads, loads some data from SQLite and displays the results. Very Strange!

Comment: @PaulWalton I don't think this is something we can discover without the code.